# Maximizing symbolic expression

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic

How can I maximize the following symbolic expression in Mathematica, assuming that $da, db \ge 0$?

$\delta(a,b,da,db) = ((a \pm da) (b \pm db)) (1 + y) - ab$

My problem on the first place is that I don't know how to represent a meaningful $\pm$ operator in Mathematica, since `PlusMinus` is just an eye candy which performs formatting only:

```
\[Delta] = ((a + PlusMinus[da])(b + PlusMinus[db])) (1 + y) - ab;
```

I want something like

```
Subscript[\[Delta], 0] = ((a + da)*(b + db)) (1 + y) - (a*b);
Subscript[\[Delta], 1] = ((a - da)*(b + db)) (1 + y) - (a*b);
Subscript[\[Delta], 2] = ((a + da)*(b - db)) (1 + y) - (a*b);
Subscript[\[Delta], 3] = ((a - da)*(b - db)) (1 + y) - (a*b);
\[Delta] = 
  Max[Subscript[\[Delta], 0], Subscript[\[Delta], 1], 
   Subscript[\[Delta], 2], Subscript[\[Delta], 3]];
```

Comment: Here its considered helpful and polite show your own efforts and share your **coded equations** and code attempts in a well [formatted form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly.

Comment: @rhermans If you read my question, it is clear that I ask because I have do not even know how to represent the expression in Mathematica. How would I proceed?

Comment: You want to maximize `\[Delta][y]` or `\[Delta][y,a,b]`? In addition it is not clear what the use of  `PlusMinus` stands for.  Do you want to maximize four variations of `\[Delta]` ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I updated my answer, but yeah, I want to generate four variations and determine the one which produces the maximum value.

Comment: @plasmacel  y is a constant parameter?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes.

Comment: BTW, You should avoid using [`Subscript`](https://goo.gl/sa5ME8) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [Downvalue](https://goo.gl/c5z1S2) to the oprator `Subscript` and not an Ownvalue to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://goo.gl/yj1VuQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is an approach. This function takes an expression in the first argument and changes the signs of all the variables listed in the second argument, for all possible [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html)

```
ToggleSign[expr_, vars_] := ReplaceAll[
  expr
  , Map[
   MapThread[
     Rule[#1, #2 #1] &
     , {vars, #}
     ] &
   , Tuples[
    {-1, 1}
    , Length[vars]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

So now you can just do

```
Max[
 ToggleSign[
  ((a + da)*(b + db)) (1 + y) - (a*b)
  , {da, db}
  ]
 ]
```

> ```
> Max[-a b + (a - da) (b - db) (1 + y), -a b + (a + da) (b - db) (1 + 
>      y), -a b + (a - da) (b + db) (1 + y), -a b + (a + da) (b + 
>      db) (1 + y)]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Get conditions for the order of the equations {d1,d2,d3,d4}.

Regard all permutations.

```
perm = Permutations[{d4, d3, d2, d1}]

perm2 = Less @@ # & /@ perm

perm3 = ToString[#] & /@ perm2

{d1 = ((a + da)*(b + db)) (1 + y) - (a*b),
 d2 = ((a - da)*(b + db)) (1 + y) - (a*b),
 d3 = ((a + da)*(b - db)) (1 + y) - (a*b),
 d4 = ((a - da)*(b - db)) (1 + y) - (a*b)}

Table[Simplify[{perm3[[i]], 
    Reduce[perm2[[i]] && da > 0 && db > 0 && y > -1, {a, b, da, db}, 
       Reals]}, da > 0 && db > 0 && y > -1], {i, 1, 
       Length[perm2]}] // TableForm
```

[image]